# Adding time delay to a state space model

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Let's say that I have a discrete state space model with delay:

$$x(k+1) = A_dx(k)+B_du(k-L)\\y(k)= C_dx(k) +D_du(k-L) $$

Can I insted just remove delay $L$ from $B_du(k-L)$ and $D_du(k-L)$ and simulate without delay.

Then when I need to plot $y(k)$ against discrete time $t_d(k) $ , can I insted just add delay $L$ to $t_d(k)$ so it becomes $t_d(k) + L$.

Or is this not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if the input $u(k)$ is not a function of the state $x(k)$ or output $y(k)$. So the input should only be a function of time.

Also in order to get the same transient at the start when using a certain initial state $x(0)$ you would have to add $L$ zeros in front of the desired $u(t)$. If your system is stable, has fast dynamics relative to the planned simulated time and you are not interested in this start up transient, you could omit the zeros.

Comment: Ok. So I have to compute the discrete delay which are delay time divided by sampling intervall. I think I have to round that to an integer and use a if statement and a counter for the input. You know what i'm mean ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson You can also generate a discrete time state space model with a delay that isn't an integer multiple of the sample time (assuming zero order hold, so from $t(k)$ till $t(k+1)$ $u(t)$ is constant) from a continues time state space model. So you could convert this discrete model into continuous (you would have to add the previous input as a state into the model).

Comment: How can I create a discrete state space model with delay? I assume that state space model has an internal delay?

Comment: I found out that I need a augmented state space model with the dimension $n+delay/sampletime $ as $A $ matrix.

Comment: Or do you think that I can use algoritms to simulate a delay?